# Durandal: Determining if a view is currently active (possibly using Router)?

Tags: durandal

My shell has buttons that should be displayed only if the user is currently viewing a certain viewModel.  How can I determine whether or not a view is currently "active" from the shell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the routes are defined in `shell.js` `activate` then using `viewAttached` will allow access to the `router` object.

```
return {
    router: router,
    viewAttached: function () {
        console.log('activeRoute', router.activeRoute());
    },
    activate: function () {
        router.map([...
```

**Update** based on comment

In Durandal 2.x `activeRoute()` isn't defined any longer. Use `router.activeInstruction()` instead.

**Update 2** based on comment

In Durandal 2.x `viewAttached` is now `attached`.

> **Note**: For those who need access to the current route's configuration
>   in order to get at custom properties or other information, you can
>   access the raw data via router.activeInstruction() The instruction
>   contains the fragment, queryString, params, and queryParams. It also
>   contains a config property which is the same instance as your original
>   route config.

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/

Comment: This is working when I first load the page, but activeRoute isn't changing if I change the view.  Any idea why that would be happening?

Comment: If you're using `cacheviews: true` in your composition turn it off. See http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/ for detail.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code. Can you fork https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2 and create a fiddle for that?

Comment: I've never used git before :(  I need to take a break from this anyways, I'll try again later.  Thank you

Comment: In case this helps - if I add 'router.activeRoute().moduleId' to my view, it updates as I click through my app.  But if I assign that value to an observable 'routeId' in viewAttached of shell.js, routeId is defined once but never again, presumably because the shell only loads once.  I need to access the activeRoute from within shell.js, not the view... does that help at all?

Comment: Coming closer :). `router.activeRoute` is an observable, so something along the following (before you call router.activate('myroute') should do what you're looking for.
`router.activeRoute.subscribe(function(val){
       console.log('ActiveRoute', val);
    });`

Comment: I try this: `router.activeRoute()`, and in console log `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'activeRoute'`.

Comment: For Durandal 2.0 try `router.activeInstruction()` http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/

Comment: `viewAttached` is `attached` in Durandal 2.0, jic.